# update column of a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have some issue regarding update column of a table in PostgreSQL

My PostgreSQL version is 9.3
Eg:

In below example jifileresource is the table and column name is DATA
public is the schema

bytea_import is the function to retrieve the content of a file

```
UPDATE jifileresource
  SET DATA=(SELECT public.bytea_import('D:/BOB_XML/BOB.xml')
WHERE ID=2235;
```

i am getting error like this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 4: WHERE ID=2235
                     ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at end of input
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening two parentheses and closing only one.

```
UPDATE jifileresource
  SET DATA = (SELECT public.bytea_import('D:/BOB_XML/BOB.xml')) <-- here a ")" was missing
WHERE ID=2235;
```

Comment: @user3797729 in the beginning its common don't worry about it